# Umbraco v 4.7.1.1 slow loading

Tags: umbraco

I have set up a completely new virtual server. A Windows Server 2008R2 Datacenter Edition with a MS-SQL 2008R2 Standard Edition on the same server. The server uses 2 CPUs and has a memory off 4 GB. There, so to say, pretty sufficient power on the machine.

On the server I have only five Umbraco websites installed.

But I have a very slow loading on my Umbraco ver 4.7.1.1 installation. When I run ?umbDebugShowTrace=true I get that:

Category: umbracoInit
Message: handling request
From First(s): 4.60952439486024E-05
From Last(s): 0,000046

All other Categories are very fast. Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is?

Comment: What's the nature of the page? Does it list stuff? Does it list every node in the website? Does it list every piece of internet everywhere, ever?

Comment: Its just a ordinary website. A workcopy can be found here: http://st5.workcopy.net/

Comment: Which page is slow? The home page?

Answer (score 2):

Having accessed http://st5.workcopy.net/?umbDebugShowTrace=true (which shows your website stack trace), you main problem is in your NavigationSelect macro, which starts rendering at 0.015-0.016 seconds into the page lifecycle, and completes rendering at 8.52 seconds into the cycle. May I suggest you look into improving the method calls in that macro (are you calling `library.NiceUrl()` a lot?), as that seems to be the source of your page load speeds.

Your FirstPageBoxes macro also seems to be attempting an awful lot of static type conversions, which indicates a lot of calls to a property (e.g. `Model.MyProperty`) that has an underlying complex type (such as an XML block - YouTube data type, perhaps?) - maybe you should call this once into a separate, strongly-typed variable so that your cast is only performed once at runtime, thus improving the macro performance further.